# Read and loop inside private folder with fs (filesystem) using Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have files inside a specific folder located in private area on Meteor. I would like to loop inside to get each file inside this folder with a loop, using this :

```
readdirSync(folder).forEach(function(file) {
// Files that i want to get (file)
console.log(file) 
});
```

But i really don't know how i supposed to do to get path of the folder's destination on Meteor. I read a little about (assets) but I feel like it works only for a specific file.

Bye, and thanks.
CaPiTo26

Answer (score 0):

Some guesswork here, but assuming you know the name of one of the files, you could get its absolute path using `Assets.absoluteFilePath(assetPath)`*. Then use Node's `path.dirname`** to get the absolute directory of the files, then use `fs.readdir`*** to loop through the files in the directory.

- *https://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html
- **https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_dirname_path
- ***https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback